# Relationship between Levi Civitá connections

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, isometry, connections, pullback

I tried to prove the statement below using the properties of the Lie bracket and the isometry. I could not prove it, the pull back function ($ f _ {*} $) does not appear by multiplying the $ M $ manifolds connection. Can someone help me please.

> Let $\left( M, g \right)$ and $\left(M′, g′\right)$ be Riemannian
>   manifolds, denote by $ \nabla $ and $\nabla^{'}$ the corresponding
>   Levi-Civitá connections, and let $f : M \rightarrow M′$ be an
>   isometry. It follows from the Koszul formula that $f$ maps $\nabla$ to
>   $\nabla^{'}$ is the sense that
>
> $$ {\nabla^{'}}_{f_{*}X} f_{*}Y = f_{*}\left( \nabla_{X} Y \right). $$
>
> Koszul formula is given by \begin{align} 2g ( \nabla_{X} Y, Z) = Xg(Y,
>  Z) + Y g(Z, X) − Zg(X, Y ) - g([X, Y ], Z) - g([Z, X], Y ) - g([Z, Y
>  ], X) \end{align}

Thank!

Comment: So, if you write $f_*U = U'$ for any vector field $U$ on $M$,  what do you know about $g'(U',V')$, $[U',V']$? Can you deduce that $g'(\nabla'_{X'}Y',Z') = g'((\nabla_XY)',Z')$?

Comment: $g'(U', V') = g(U,V)$  or $g'(U', V') = f_{*}g(U,V)$ ? why?@TedShifrin

Comment: I know that $[U',V']=f_{*}[U,V]$ @TedShifrin

Comment: For your question above, because $f$ is an isometry. You definitely need to use that! :)

Comment: $f_{*}$ is push-forward from $U$ by $f$? No, pull-back. Thank! @TedShifrin

Comment: $f^g’ = g$, since the metric tensor is covariant.

Comment: But,$ 2g' ( {\nabla_{'}}_{X'} Y', Z') = X'g'(Y',
 Z') + Y' g'(Z', X') − Z'g'(X', Y' ) - g'([X', Y' ], Z') - g'([Z', X'], Y' ) - g'([Z', Y'], X') = X'g(Y,  Z) + Y' g(Z, X) − Z'g(X, Y ) - g([X, Y ], Z) - g([Z, X], Y ) - g([Z, Y], X) $.I can't finish.@TedShifrin

Comment: Be careful. You can't differentiate a function on $M$ with a vector field on $M'$.